# why is the time limit exceeding on this reversal linked list?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
public class Solution {
    public ListNode reverseList(ListNode head) {
        if(head == null){
            return head;
        }
        System.out.println(head.val);
       ListNode tail = new ListNode(head.val);
       head = head.next;
       while(head != null){
           tail.next = tail;
           tail.val = head.val;
           head = head.next;
       }
       return tail;
    }
}
```

On Leetcode I am trying to reverse a singly linked list, here is an issue, why isnt it doing it in time?

With the input `[1, 2]`, it shows time limit exceeded, but I don't see why. Can someone help?

Comment: Do you really need to print out the `head.val`? As a wild guess, that might have significant overhead, especially compared to the rest of the code.

Comment: How long does it actually take to run if you run it independently?

Comment: @KenY-N, I took it out and now I have a memory limit exceeded error

Comment: @DavidWallace, I am not sure, how can I tell?

Comment: By running it?  Just roughly how long does it take?

Comment: **tail.next = tail** , keeps saying that the **.next** for **tail** is **tail**. You are failing to create the appropriate link in the statement **tail.next = tail** , because the **next** of the **tail** points back to **tail**, causing tail.next reference to be overwritten by tail reference

Comment: @ShayHaned, then how does something like "x = x + 4" work with x being an integer?

Comment: Well, once you set `tail.next` to `tail`, you no longer have a list that ends with `null` - instead, you have a list that ends with a tight little loop that you can never escape from.

Comment: @Onedayanam Please pay a little attention to what David Wallace mentioned. I am trying to communicate exactly the same thing

Comment: @DavidWallace, thanks. Is there a way to fix?

Comment: Well, don't do `tail.next = tail;`.  Honestly, I think you need to sit down with pencil and paper and work out exactly how your algorithm is supposed to work, before you write any more code.

Comment: @DavidWallace, thanks for the help, I'll do just that